# Is it possible to execute a delete query on the default retention policy in influxdb?

Tags: influxdb, retention, influxql

Influx database named "metrics" with two retention policy and assign one as default out of the two.

```
CREATE RETENTION POLICY basic ON "metrics" DURATION 2h  REPLICATION 1 SHARD DURATION 6m DEFAULT
CREATE RETENTION POLICY downsample ON "metrics" DURATION 60d  REPLICATION 1 SHARD DURATION 2h
```

There is also bunch of continuous queries runs at every 10 mins and downsample the data to write influx **downsample** retention policy tier. The entries available at the **basic** retention policy tier got cleared every 2h and *downsample* retention policy clears after 60 days.

Continuous query sample looks like this

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY "cq_reads" ON "metrics" BEGIN SELECT sum(reads) as reads INTO downsample.stats_io FROM "metrics".basic.stats_io GROUP BY time(10m),* END
```

**metrics** is the database name and **stats_io** is the measurement here.

I have memory constraint of specified GB allowed for influx in my product. At some point influx started to fail in scaling to hold 60 days data.

I am trying to clear oldest 10 mins data in *basic* retention policy after hitting my memory limits. The corresponding downsampled oldest 10 mins data are still need to be available at *downsample* retention policy.

Following command deletes last ten mins data in both **basic** and **downsample** retention policies.

```
delete stats_io where time>1609457374835790623 and time < 1609457374835790623 + 10m
```

I don't want to delete the downsampled data available at *downsample* retention policy. So tried to delete *basic* retention policy alone.

```
delete basic.stats_io where time>1609457374835790623 and time < 1609457374835790623 + 10m
```

unfortunately this query ends up in error and doesn't allow to delete based on retention policies.

```
ERR: error parsing query: found basic, expected FROM, WHERE at line 1, char 8
```

However select query works properly with specific retention policy. But delete doesn't work as the same way. Example: select query

```
select count(*) from basic.stats_io // Properly get the count for the measurement with specified retention policy
```

I am wondering why the delete doesn't support retention policy based deletes. Is it any other approach or queries exist to clear the default retention policy data alone ?

Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the syntax `delete FROM`

```
delete FROM basic.stats_io where time>1609457374835790623 and time < 1609457374835790623 + 10m
```

More info here in [DELETE documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/database_management/#delete-series-with-delete)